# Probability of correct forecast in a football match.

Tags: probability

The question is :
A football match may either won, drawn or lost by the host country's team. So there are three ways of forecasting the results of any one match, one correct and two incorrect. Find the probability of forecasting at least three correct results for four matches.

I calculated it as $\frac19$ but I am not satisfied with my answer as someone I know calculated it different and his answer is $\frac{5}{81}$ .
So please assist in finding the answer and approach.

Comment: FYI this is the binomial distribution with $n=4, p=1/3$.

Comment: Your friend is wrong. You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add up the following:**

---

The probability of forecasting exactly $\color\red3$ correct results for $4$ matches:

$$\binom{4}{\color\red3}\cdot\left(\frac13\right)^{\color\red3}\cdot\left(1-\frac13\right)^{4-\color\red3}=\frac{8}{81}$$

---

The probability of forecasting exactly $\color\red4$ correct results for $4$ matches:

$$\binom{4}{\color\red4}\cdot\left(\frac13\right)^{\color\red4}\cdot\left(1-\frac13\right)^{4-\color\red4}=\frac{1}{81}$$